# CodeIgniter + HTML5 Boilerplate + Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, boilerplate

I'm trying to start a new project, and was looking for the "ultimate" package to kick-start off with for PHP/MySQL/HTML5 development. Tried CodeIgniter first, which was great. Then discovered Twitter Bootstrap, and integrated that in nicely. Finally, found HTML5 Boilerplate, which looked awesome, and saw that some people were putting together mixes of these three.

Was wondering if anyone has actually been able to put together and run an integration of all three well? I see there's a github repo for this: https://github.com/vesparny/codeigniter-html5boilerplate-twitter-bootstrap, but I couldn't find any StackOverflow inquiries on it. Anyone have some experience they could share before I jump in? Didn't want to spend days trying to figure it out, just to find out it would've been easier/better to just stick with pure CodeIgniter or just HTML5BP.

Comment: Codeingiter is a php(server-side) framework, html5boilerplate/twitter-bootstrap are a collection of (frontend) libraries, IE only affect html/css/js.

Comment: Hey @Philip, yeah sorry I think "installation" was poor wording. I mean something more like an "integration" of all three. The three parts seem to cover different things like you mentioned (framework, html/js, css), so wanted to know if anyone had experience combining all three in a good way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i'm the author of that library you've looking into. https://github.com/vesparny/codeigniter-html5boilerplate-twitter-bootstrap

Tw bootstrap and H5BP can be simply mixed together as you can see in my code;
Codeigniter is a great framework but lacks in view organization imho.
With this library you can take advantage of the best client side tools, and the most famous and simple php framework with some enhancement that would speed up and better organize your code and approach to code with codeigniter.

Comment: Hey @Arny yeah I've been working with your library and it's great. I made a few infrastructure adjustments to it so I could pass back errors / data from the models in a more standardized way, but aside from that, it really works out of the box. Thanks for putting that out there for people to use!

Comment: @Carlin If it's a good way to do things then please send your stuff back into the project!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like not many people try this I guess, but it DOES work, and it works fine as far as I can tell.

CodeIgniter works well as the php framework, and you can integrate the HTML5 BP to render your pages in a HTML5-friendly way, with a few javascript libraries like Initialzr's modernizer to help with loading resources. CodeIgniter is pretty fast, and there is pretty much zero conflict when combining CI with HTML5 BP, making it a pretty quick and painless addition.

Twitter Bootstrap works fine as well, since it's mainly CSS and javascript plugins for components, which you can merge with HTML5's plugins.js file if you want / need it. I'd say that after playing with this, Twitter Bootstrap isn't really necessary, but it does help you put together a responsive front-end pretty quickly. Not sure if there are other packages out there that might be better.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to run an installation of css and javascript file?
Take HTML5 Boilerplate and Twitter bootstrap files and copy them into your website root directory (directory where is your Codeigniter application folder located).
Now you can use them as any other javascript/html/css libraries and frameworks.
And I still don't know why are you trying to use Twitter Bootstrap with HTML5 Boilerplate. I am not using any of these but they look similar. It looks like a little overhead for your website.

Comment: Hey @shaggy, yeah sorry perhaps "run an installation" wasn't the best wording. I meant an "integration" of all three together. The reason for the HTML5BP + TwitterBT request is because it seems like they're out there for different reasons, and could be integrated for a great default starting application with quick CSS scaffolding for components? See: http://www.quora.com/Is-Bootstrap-a-complement-OR-an-alternative-to-HTML5-Boilerplate-or-viceversa. Just wanted to see if others had opinions on these.

Comment: @Carlin - you can combine any javascript and css files, so there isn't any issue with using these two "frameworks" together. Install (unpack) Codeigniter, add Boilerplate, add Boostrap, build your web using any or all of them, run your web. Do you have any problems with it?

Comment: yeah I eventually just went ahead and did it. It seems to be working fine and I haven't had any issues with it. This post was more to see if anyone else had done it and if they had any advice on using it. Wanted to know if, say for example, the HTML5 BP css didn't merge well with the Bootstrap CSS, or maybe there's a better package to use than Twitter Bootstrap / CodeIgniter, etc. Thanks for your input anyway!